# How to get descriptor from gpuHog?

Tags: opencv, feature-descriptor

I used CPU version as follows.

```
vector<float> descriptors;
cv::HOGDescriptor hog(cv::Size(24,32),cv::Size(12,12),cv::Size(4,4),cv::Size(6,6),6);
hog.compute(img, descriptors,cv::Size(8,8), cv::Size(0,0));
```

My questions is how can get the 'descriptors' using GPU?

I tried the following code. (doesn't work)

```
cv::gpu::GpuMat gpu_value, gpu_descriptors;
cv::gpu::HOGDescriptor hog_gpu(Size(24,32),Size(12,12),Size(4,4),Size(6,6),6);
gpu_value.upload(img);
hog_gpu.getDescriptors(gpu_value,cv::Size(8,8),gpu_descriptors);
```

how can I get the 'descriptors' from 'gpu_descriptors'?

Any one can help me to solve this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download `gpu_descriptors` to CPU memory using `gpu::GpuMat` memeber function `download()`, as follows:

```
Mat cpu_descriptors; 
gpu_descriptors.download(cpu_descriptors);
```

However, the descriptors may be stored differently on the GPU than on CPU, that is `cpu_descriptors` may not be exactly the same as `descriptors` computed in your code above. But you can give it a try.

**Edit**
There doesn't seem to be a method to download descriptors to CPU memory in `vector<float>` format for `gpu::HOGDescriptor`. As a side note, I know that you can download descriptors for [`gpu::SURF_GPU`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=surf#gpu%3a%3aSURF_GPU) feature detector, using it's member function

```
void downloadDescriptors(const GpuMat& descriptorsGPU,
    vector<float>& descriptors);
```

which is exactly what you want. But, unfortunately, for some reason this function doesn't exist for `cv::gpu::HOGDescriptor`. You can attempt to figure out how the data is stored in `vector<float>` type of descriptors and then try to convert from `Mat` to `vector<float>` format.

Comment: Hi Alex, is it possible to convert cpu_descriptors to a vector?

Comment: cv::gpu::HOGDescriptor hog_gpu(Size(24,32),Size(12,12),Size(4,4),Size(6,6),6); seems some problems here. can u help? thanks

Comment: The program crash @ cv::gpu::HOGDescriptor hog_gpu(Size(24,32),Size(12,12),Size(4,4),Size(6,6),6); It works okay when I use cv::gpu::HOGDescriptor hog_gpu. Don't know the problem. I use x64 platform

Comment: @user3203629 In the parameters to the constructor: Block stride must be a multiple of cell size. See the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/object_detection.html?highlight=hog#gpu-hogdescriptor-hogdescriptor). In your case `Size(4,4`) is not a multiple of `Size(6,6)`. Also, nbins – Number of bins. Only 9 bins per cell are supported for now. In your case nbins =6. In summary, make sure you set the parameters according to the documentation